# How do we import a self-signed certificate for the Polkadot-JS electron app or AppImage?

Tags: polkadot-js

According to https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/maintain-wss#importing-the-certificate
One can visit the cloud instance on `https` and download the certificate and then proceed to connect to a websocket via 443, but how can one achieve this using the electron App or Polkadot Appimage? I am currently on windows, and I can connect to my cloud via my browser, but not via my electron app, supposedly because my app cannot obtain the certificate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a couple of options:

- If you are using a browser, you can do what it says in the docs - by clicking on "Proceed to site" in the browser pop-up the self-signed certificate should become whitelisted - which should then allow you to connect to a local node using the browser Polkadot interface.
- If you are using electron, you most likely won't get the "Proceed to site" popup since this is usually browser-specific - though a similar popup could be implemented in the Polkadot-JS electron app if you want to contribute to the repository: https://github.com/polkadot-js/apps
- You can expose the node endpoint on a public server port and create a certificate signed by a real certificate authority e.g. Let's encrypt (https://letsencrypt.org/docs/) - then you should be able to connect with Electron/Browser without any issues but this could be problematic if you want to keep the node private on localhost.
- Another option is to generate your own certificate, either self-signed or signed by a local root, and trust it in your operating system’s trust store. Then use that certificate in your local node's websocket endpoint.

The process of adding a self-signed certificate to a local trust store is different based on different operating systems:

On Arch/Fedora Linux ([update-ca-trust](https://man.archlinux.org/man/update-ca-trust.8)):

1. Copy the self-signed certificate to:

```
/etc/ca-certificates/trust-source/anchors/mycertificate.crt
```

2. Update the trust store (as root):

```
sudo update-ca-trust
```

On Ubuntu/Debian Linux ([security-trust-store](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/security-trust-store)):

1. Copy the self-signed certificate to:

```
/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/mycertificate.crt
```

2. Update the trust store (as root):

```
sudo update-ca-certificates
```

I'm less familiar with how to do this on Windows but I found an article online that might be of use:

[make-a-self-signed-certificate-trusted-on-windows](https://www.ntweekly.com/2020/08/31/make-a-self-signed-certificate-trusted-on-windows/)

And here's an article on how to do this on MacOS:

[trust-self-signed-certificates-macos](https://readwriteexercise.com/posts/trust-self-signed-certificates-macos/)

> 1. Open Keychain Access and the All Items category (lower left)
> 2. Locate your self-signed certificate file (.pem, .p12, or something else) in Finder
> 3. Drag your certificate file from Finder to Keychain Access, in the list on the right
> 4. Open Certificates on the very bottom left
> 5. Find the certificate you just dragged in and double click it (if there’s a dropdown arrow on the left then just ignore that, we want the top level one)
> 6. Click the Trust dropdown arrow then change When using this certificate from System Defaults to Always Trust

Comment: Great answer. The only caveat stopping me from using Let's encrypt is getting a domain name. But I'm sure it's the easiest method out of all.